# Why is acceleration the same in both frames in a Galilean transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I'm confused about this expression showing that the acceleration in a stationary frame is the same as that in a moving frame:

$$a'=\frac{d^2r'}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(r-Vt)=\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}+0=a$$

How do you get the $+0$ part of the expression? Does this imply that the second time derivative of $-Vt=0$?

Would this then mean that $V$ is constant? And if so why isn't $r$ constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Galilean transformation, the velocity $V$ in $r' = r - Vt$ is constant. A derivative of a constant is $0$. 
In detail: 
$$ \begin{equation} \frac{d^2}{dt^2} (r-Vt) = \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - \frac{d}
{dt}\frac{d(Vt)}{dt} \end{equation} \\
= \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - \frac{dV}{dt} \\
= \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} - 0 $$

If $r$ also were a constant, the equation would be still correct. Therefore it applies: $a= 0$.

Answer (score 1):

V is the relative speed of the two frames of reference, and must be a constant if its derivative with respect to time is zero.

r is the position of the accelerating body, and must be varying if the body is accelerating.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is change of velocity w.r.t change of time.
If we observe the velocity change..it will be same , the reason is that inertia frames which says that frame have constant acceleration or zero acceleration which means both frames have equal acceleration even the other frame starts moving (it has constant velocity (a=0). )